# Meteor : How to implement a private message in a chat room?

Tags: chat, meteor, privacy

Actually I'm more interested in the techniques to use to achieve this task more than really building a chat system (which is an excellent concrete example). I see 2 parts:

1. The client needs to get registered somewhere, and we then need a unique ID per client.
2. The server should be able to send something to the client only from another client.

For the first part, I do not know how to get this unique id. Possibly using the new meteor auth kit ?

For the second part, I thought about building a per-client collection in which one and only one client will have access to, but it sounds heavy and In my opinion not really in the Meteor best practice. I then thought of adding a "from" and to "field" to a Message (see the regular [chat example](https://github.com/AVGP/meteor.js-chat-example)). This would do it but I'm wondering about the no privacy on them. Would a custom publish returning a filtered find do it or it is risky too i.e. would other client get the items too ? Something like:

```
Meteor.publish("message", function (clientID) {
  return Messages.find({"dest":clientID }, {});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Meteor todos example uses the new auth system to identify private todo entries. I would imagine that you could use the same mechanism to identify the originator and recipient of a private message in a chat like system.

Of course the filtering of which messages someone sees would need to be filtered on the server side to maintain privacy.

Comment: Auth system -> ok,
The filtering -> do we achieve this in making a "custom" publish ? I do not really get exactly how those publish works, is that simply a way to restrict the collection set according to a parameter ? If so, is it possible to have 2 publish on the same collection name ? (I can imagine it is not the case)

Comment: It seems that each time a client subscribes, a private subscription is established and this can include client specific info (e.g. user id). The API ref for publish() says it basically declares  "... a publish function that Meteor will call each time a client subscribes to the name."  See the auth todos example for the publish using the user id: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/auth/examples/todos/server/publish.js

Comment: ok therefore we virtually restrict the collection according to some filters. Then we work on this collection only. As I see publishing 2 times the same collection name with different "filters" is not possible (neither recommended). Thank you, this answered to my question =)